# TextLayout, when direction is rtl brackets do not render correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have noticed a rendering problem when using `TextLayout` where brackets don't render correctly when they are on the start of a new line.  So:

```
    public function TestTextLayout()
    {
        basic(" The Intel Core i7 Processor (720QM)", 500, 500);
    }

    public function basic(text:String, width:int, height:int):void {
        var textFlow:TextFlow = new TextFlow();
        var p:ParagraphElement = new ParagraphElement();
        textFlow.addChild(p);

        var span:SpanElement = new SpanElement();
        span.text = text;
        span.fontSize = 40;
        p.addChild(span);

        textFlow.direction = Direction.RTL;
        textFlow.flowComposer.addController(new ContainerController(this, width, height));
        textFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();

        debug("line height = " + p.lineHeight);
    }
```

Creates the following text:

```
The Intel Core i7 Processor 
720QM
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Just a poke in the dark try basic(" The Intel Core i7 Processor &#40720QM&#41", 500, 500);

Comment: @The_asMan thanks your response but this didn't work unfortunately, I also tried using unicode characters with no success!

Comment: I don't know I have never used SpanElement before. But one thing for sure the String is either getting changed somehow or the data encoding for it cant handle non-ascii characters. Curious try taking out the parenthesis and see what happens.

Comment: @The_asMan when the parenthesis are taken out the text reads ok:

"The Intel Core i7 Processor
720QM"

But right aligned of course! It works when using Hebrew or Arabic but not Simple Chinese or English, maybe this is because the translated text is running right to left for Hebrew and Arabic.

Comment: Ok I found out why, it's simply that Chinese is a left to right language, when a language is right to left, the text renders ok! doh!

Comment: Odd but I will take your word on that one.